Chrome Web Socket getting aborted frequently
I have a opened a Remote debugging port on Chrome and managing its tabs and navigations throgh CDP.
But I could see the Chrome WebSocket for remote debugging is getting closed frequently with error "The remote party closed the WebSocket Connection without completing the close handshake"
In the chrome log I could see error like
a. Too Large Write data is pending.
b. Invalid parse_blocked_on_script_execution_duration.
Why does the WebSocket getting closed frequently?
I am sending hunderds of CDP commands? Does this cause the WebSocket to get aborted?
Suggest checks or modifications that are required to avoid the frequent Abort of WebSocket.
